# How to write in firebase from directive

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework

I'm try to write something to firebase from directive

This is my directive [UPDATED]:

```
angular.module('MyApp.directives').directive('score', function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      scope: {
      },
      templateUrl: 'dashboard/score.html',
      controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {

      }],
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller, firebase) {

          var eventsRef = new Firebase('https://URL.firebaseio.com/');
          scope.event_id = attrs.index;
          //Score counter
          scope.Score = [0, 0];
          scope.add_btn = function(num) {
            scope.Score[num]++;
          };
          scope.dist_btn = function(num) {    
            if (scope.Score[num] > 0) {
              scope.Score[num]--;
            } else {
              num = 0;
            }
          };

          scope.setPrediction = function () {
            eventsRef.child('/'+scope.event_id+'/').update(scope.Score);
          }
        }
      }
});
```

And it's throw error:

> FIREBASE INTERNAL ERROR: Server Error: ClientId[7373865]:ErrorId[2]: Error on incoming message

Comment: Writing to Firebase (using their Web/JavaScript API) is as simple as `new Firebase('https//your.firebaseio.com/path/to/node').set({ prop: "value" })`. What is the problem you're having?

Comment: What is the value of `scope.Score` just before you call `update(scope.Score)`?

Comment: it's depends, on user choice. But in general it's looks like [4,5], or any other two numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I realize wats happend. Firebase don;t like to post arrays without key's

This code is working:

```
angular.module('MyApp.directives').directive('score', function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      scope: {
      },
      templateUrl: 'dashboard/score.html',
      controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {

      }],
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller, firebase) {

          var eventsRef = new Firebase('https://sportsbettr2.firebaseio.com/events');
          scope.event_id = attrs.index;
          //Score counter
          scope.Score = [0, 0];
          scope.add_btn = function(num) {
            scope.Score[num]++;
          };
          scope.dist_btn = function(num) {    
            if (scope.Score[num] > 0) {
              scope.Score[num]--;
            } else {
              num = 0;
            }
          };

          scope.setPrediction = function () {
            eventsRef.child('/'+scope.event_id+'/').update({
                "score": scope.Score
            });
          }
        }
      }
});
```

Comment: Hmmm... that was my initial expectation that `update` doesn't like arrays, but I tested a simple `ref.update([0, 0])` and that worked fine. Well anyway: great that you found how to fix the problem and thanks for posting it. Don't forget to accept your self-answer once the system allows it.